# My Fibonacci sequence as a recursive function is an infinite loop

Tags: perl, recursion, fibonacci

The following function recurses infinitely and I don't see why. It enters the conditional statements but doesn't seem to be terminating with the `return` statement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print fibonacci(100);

sub fibonacci {

    my $number = shift;

    if ($number == 0) {
        print "return 0\n";
        return 0;
    }
    elsif ($number == 1) {
        print "return 1\n";
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return fibonacci($number-1) + fibonacci($number-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a much smaller number as input.

Comment: It's not in an infinite loop; it's just taking a really long time (and might trigger checks designed to detect infinite loops because of how deep it runs the stack.)

Answer (score 5):

Your loop does not recurse infinitely, it just takes way too long with an input of 100. Try a memoized version:

```
{ my @fib;
  sub fib {
    my $n = shift;
    return $fib[$n] if defined $fib[$n];
    return $fib[$n] = $n if $n < 2;
    $fib[$n] = fib($n-1) + fib($n-2);
  }
}
```

Comment: This manual memorization beats the performance of `Memoize` by a factor of 2 on my machine, though there's something to be said for the automation and consistency of using the module.

Comment: @MarkReed: I doubt if you'll find many people who care whether they get a result in fifteen milliseconds or seven.

Comment: @MarkReed Memoize uses a hash to implement the cache because it covers the general case. The use of an array for this particular example is probably the source of the greater performance.

Answer (score 3):

You code can be made much more concise, and speeded up massively by memoizing it.

The [`Memoize`](https://metacpan.org/module/Memoize) module is by far the simplest and clearest way to memoize (cache the results of) a subroutine.

I suggest this version. It still warns about deep recursion but it produces a value that I presume is correct.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Memoize;
memoize('fibonacci');

print fibonacci(100);

sub fibonacci {
    my ($n) = @_;
    $n < 2 ? $n : fibonacci($n-1) + fibonacci($n-2);
}
```

**output**

```
Deep recursion on anonymous subroutine at E:\Perl\source\fib.pl line 11.
Deep recursion on anonymous subroutine at E:\Perl\source\fib.pl line 11.
3.54224848179262e+020
```

Comment: The rewrite of the function body is fine if you're playing code golf, but otherwise unnecessary. Just using `memoize` on OP's definition speeds it up to the point that it returns the 100th Fibonacci number in less than 15 milliseconds on my machine.

Comment: @MarkReed: That is far from being code golf. All the necessary whitespace is in place to make its meaning clear. If you are uncomfortable with the conditional operator then I sympathise, but people used to reading Perl code would find it very much easier to read than the fourteen-line original.

Comment: I can read it just fine; I'm just saying the change was not necessary for the performance boost. :)

Comment: @MarkReed: No Mark, you said the change was *"fine if you're playing code golf, but otherwise unnecessary"*. That is a different thing from *"not necessary for the performance boost"*.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive function call is not infinite.  It's just going to take a long time.

One should beware recursive functions, as it's often better to code something using a loop if it can be designed as such.

In this case, your number of recursive calls to `fibonacci` are growing exponentially.  You can test this out yourself very easily by simply adding up the lower level calls

- `fibonacci(0)` = 1 call
- `fibonacci(1)` = 1 call
- `fibonacci(2)` = 1 call + calls for `fibonacci(1)` + calls for `fibonacci(0)` → 3
- `fibonacci(3)` = 1 call + calls for `fibonacci(2)` + calls for `fibonacci(1)` → 5
- `fibonacci(4)` = 1 call + calls for `fibonacci(3)` + calls for `fibonacci(2)` → 9
- `fibonacci(5)` = 1 call + calls for `fibonacci(4)` + calls for `fibonacci(3)` → 15
- `fibonacci(N)` = 1 call + calls for `fibonacci(N-1)` + calls for `fibonacci(N-2)` → ?

As you can see there is a fibonacci like growth for the number of subroutine calls.

To determine the number of calls for `fibonacci(100)` we can simply create a quick perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -e '
    @c = (1, 1); 
    $c[$_] = 1 + $c[$_-1] + $c[$_-2] for (2..100);
    print $c[100]
  ' 
1.14629568802763e+21
```

At 1 trillion calls a second, that's still going to take more than 31 years to finish.

#### Fix using Memoize

One fix that has already been proposed is to use the core library [`Memoize`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html)

```
use Memoize;
memoize('fibonacci');
```

This module will wrap around your subroutine call and cache the calculation of values.  This will therefore reduce your number of function calls from 1.14e21 to literally 101 calculations.

However, because you are recursing more than 100 times, you will get the following warning per [`perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html)

> - Deep recursion on anonymous subroutine
> - Deep recursion on subroutine "%s"
>
>   (W recursion) This subroutine has called itself (directly or indirectly) 100 times more than it has returned. This probably indicates an infinite recursion, unless you're writing strange benchmark programs, in which case it indicates something else.
>
>   This threshold can be changed from 100, by recompiling the perl binary, setting the C pre-processor macro PERL_SUB_DEPTH_WARN to the desired value.

#### Create a loop instead - avoid recursion

Your algorithm can be redesigned very easily from a top down approach to calculation to a bottom up approach.

This removes the need for recursion entirely and reduces the code to the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print fibonacci(100), "\n";

sub fibonacci {
    my $number = shift;

    my @fib = ( 0, 1 );

    for ( $#fib + 1 .. $number ) {
        $fib[$_] = $fib[ $_ - 1 ] + $fib[ $_ - 2 ];
    }

    return $fib[$number];
}
```

Outputs:

```
3.54224848179262e+20
```

No warnings will be given.